# Copyright and pound sterling symbol in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, nano

What is the proper way of inserting a copyright symbol `©` and a pound sterling symbol `£` into a bash script.

I am using `nano` as my editor and am running Debian Squeeze.

If I copy and paste the symbol from windows, it works but it seems to paste hidden characters that `nano` cannot display and it makes it hard to edit code in the shell script then.

So for example I want to be able to do this:-

```
text="£15.00"
text2="© John Doe"
```

Comment: check your locale and encoding settings, since this isn't an issue on my machine (fully utf-8).

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx how do i do this ?? (Linux newbie)

Comment: `locale` must print strings with utf-8 in them. Ok, some other compatible encoding would work too, but this is the simplest.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx output of locale are all `"C"` ?!?!?!

Comment: then you need to set these bash variables (export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8). While you could do it manually, I'm sure debian has an init.d/conf.d/profile.d/rc.d script in /etc to set it globally on system startup. All the available values on your system can be listed with `locale -a`.

Comment: Apparently it's set in /etc/environment in debian or at least was in 2010.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx wicked. Edited `/etc/default/locale` from `lang=en_GB` to `lang=en_GB.utf8` - sorted. Wanna answer the post so I can mark as answered ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using a locale that doesn't support these symbols (in the olden days it could have also been a bad font). Since you are using UTF-8 characters (default on windows), you also need to be in a UTF-8 aware environment on linux. You can check that with the `locale` command:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

So my system is fine, but yours had the default, ASCII C locale set. These are simple `bash` variables, so you could `export` them individually or override them all (by setting `LC_ALL`). However, that would only affect the current shell, so you need to make it part of shell initialisation to work everytime automatically.

This is usually done through profile scripts in `/etc` globally, but `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` would work just as well. In your version of Debian the locale is stored in `/etc/default/locale` and you can get the list of available choices with `locale -a`, eg.:

```
$ locale -a
C
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
POSIX
sl_SI.utf8
```

Pick one with an utf8 suffix. If you need other locales (for example japanese), they can be generated with localedef/locale-gen (comes with `glibc` or as a separate package).

Answer (score 1):

Better just use (C) for copyright, you want it to be always readable in other locales and not a defense for violation.

The display looks like

```
text="1.00"
text2=" ohn Doe"
```

in my test terminal.

Comment: I would say (GBP) if I want to sell it to locations that cannot display the £ sign.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having problems with entering the symbols in nano, use escape syntax.
You can use `iconv` to convert it to the output encoding corresponding to the current locale:

```
text=$'\xa315.00'
text2=$'\xa9 John Doe'
iconv -f latin1 <<< $text
iconv -f latin1 <<< $text2
```

or the same in utf8:

```
text=$'\xc2\xa315.00'
text2=$'\xc2\xa9 John Doe'
iconv -f utf-8 <<< $text
iconv -f utf-8 <<< $text2
```